# Is there a way to create a custom UUID prefix for Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to add a custom prefix to UUIDs within Laravel to help keep better track of Database entries. Currently, when called, the uuid(); function will produce a table entry like this:

```
6ab4a8c-9597-lle7-a63c-0242c100426l
```

But I would like to be able to a a prefix infront of every uuid entry within that table. For instance, Users within the Users table would have a uuid prefixed with **UUID** of:

```
UUID-6ab4a8c-9597-lle7-a63c-0242c100426l
```

and Posts would be saved in the Posts table with a **PUID** prefix:

```
PUID-6ab4a8c-9597-lle7-a63c-0242c100426l
```

to signify ('Post' Unique Identifier).

The default migration for the Users table is as follows:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

To use UUIDs, the following would be used:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->uuid('uuid')->primary();

});
```

I'm not sure where the models defining UUID(s) are stored, and I'm not sure I'd want to modify the *entire* model.

Ideally, the a uuid would be defined using the table name, then the prefix as such:

```
$table->uuid('puid', 'PUID')->primary();
```

## **Does anyone know how this could be implemented?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even with a UUID column in your database, Laravel doesn't fill it out automatically to my knowledge. That means you (or a package you install) are responsible for it.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? Seems like there should be a better solution than messing with the UUID generation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an accessor and a mutator to achieve what you want in your frontend, but the database will contain an UUID formatted value, because it's an UUID column.

In your `Users` model:

```
public function getUuidAttribute($value)
{
    return "UUID-".$value;
}

public function setUuidAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['uuid'] = str_replace("UUID-", "", $value);
}
```

and in your `Posts` Model:

```
public function getPuidAttribute($value)
{
    return "PUID-".$value;
}

public function setPuidAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['puid'] = str_replace("PUID-", "", $value);
}
```

you will see `UUID-6ab4a8c-9597-lle7-a63c-0242c100426l` when you dump `$user->uuid` and same will happen with `$post->puid` with a prefix of `PUID-`.

Otherwise, you should generate your UUID's yourself, and save them as a string in the database.